# React Router Получить props.match.params в компонентах-потомках

Tags: reactjs, react-router

В App.js

`<Route exact path='/page/:id' component={Dashboard} />`

В Dashboard.js я могу получить id, но как получить его далее не прописывая каждый раз?

Dashboard.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PokemonList from '../pokemon/PokemonList'

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        const id = this.props.match.params.id;

        return (
            <div >
                    <PokemonList id={id} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Есть ли лучший путь? А то мне потом приходится и далее его также пробрасывать.

Comment: в смысле ?Вы спрашиваете короткий путь вот этой записи  `const id = this.props.match.params.id;` ?

Comment: Нет, я спрашивал относительно чего-то вроде контекста. Чтобы мне не писать из раза в раз к компонентам в дереве `id={id}`

Comment: попробуйте контекст - https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: да кроме контекста тут вариантов нету

Comment: @TimurMusharapov какая версия react-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с `react-router` версии `2.7` был добавлен компонент высшего порядка (`HOC`) 
 - withRouter

Все компоненты где требуется доступ к параметрам, оборачивайте в `withRouter` ([подробнее](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)) - тогда вы получите в props то, что вам нужно

ES7:

```
@withRouter
class App extends ...
```

ES6:

```
class App extends ...

export default withRouter(App)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.